# Use an if statement in Javascript to determine if a cell in a google spreadsheet has contents

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code gets values from different locations in my sheet and writes the combined data to another sheet.

Problem is, if the row is blank, the code copies a blank row into the receiving sheet. I would like to first check **cell "B8"**, and if it is blank, skip this function and run the next function.

If **cell "B8"** has data in it (anything, but it will usually be a date), then I would like to run the function to copy the code to the new sheet.

Here is my code:

```js
function submitButtonClick() {

  //Begining of entry8 transfer start.
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log('sheet.getName(): ' + sheet.getName());
  
  if (sheet.getName() !== "TimeCardEntry") {return;};
  
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TimeSheetRecord");
  var arrayOfData = [];
  
  var weekBegining = sheet.getRange(4, 11).getValue();
  var employName = sheet.getRange(4, 4).getValue();
  
  var entry8 = sheet.getRange(8,2,1,9);
  var entry8Data = entry8.getValues()[0];//Get inner array of the rows data
  Logger.log('entry8Data: ' + entry8Data);

  //Add weekBegining and employName values to the array
  entry8Data.splice(0, 0, weekBegining, employName);
  //Push row data into another, outer array. setValuies() needs a 2D array.
  arrayOfData.push(entry8Data);
  
  Logger.log(arrayOfData);
  
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log('lastRow: ' + lastRow);
                                      
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, entry8Data.length).setValues(arrayOfData);
  
  sheet.getRange('B8:M8').clearContent();

    //End of entry8 transfer.
  }
```

Comment: I meant that it copies data to the target sheet, not that it copies code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some code in between these line:

```
var arrayOfData = [];

var weekBegining = sheet.getRange(4, 11).getValue();
```

Change to:

```
var arrayOfData = [];

var B8_Value = sheet.getRange(8, 2).getValue();
if (B8_Value === "") {return;};//If cell value is empty stop code here

var weekBegining = sheet.getRange(4, 11).getValue();
```